# apt package (kodi-inputstream-adaptive) does not upgrade to newest version

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, apt, kodi

I want to install this package to utilize some kodi addons. It needs version 2.4.3 at least but I can not update it to the newest version because apt thinks this is already the newest version but it definetely is not.

This is what somebody else already helped me with:

> Your system must have issues getting newer updates because Debian Buster ships with IA v2.4.4:
>   https://www.deb-multimedia.org/dists/stable/main/binary-armhf/package/kodi-inputstream-adaptive

This happens when I want to install newest version:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install kodi-inputstream-adaptive
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    kodi-inputstream-adaptive is already the newest version (2.4.2-1~buster).
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 154 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Have you updated registry first with `apt-get update` and then upgrade with `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade <packagename>`

Comment: same issue:
kodi-inputstream-adaptive is already the newest version (2.4.2-1~buster).

Comment: Seems like that it is [latest available](http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/k/kodi-inputstream-adaptive/). Raspberry packages differ bit from mainstream Debian packages.

Comment: not a way to fix it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add it manually.

Add the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

`deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org buster main`

Update packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install keyring:

```
sudo apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring
```

Then try to install it again

```
sudo apt-get install kodi-inputstream-adaptive
```

[Reference.](https://www.deb-multimedia.org/)